# How to build only the web version of a React Native project, into production?

Tags: javascript, react-native, build, production, netlify

I am new to React Native. I have created a project and want to build it into production. For now, I only want to build the web version (not android/ios app), and host it on Netlify, thus allowing others to access it. How should I proceed?

Comment: Hey. You can do it. There's a library to do it `react-native-web`. Please take a look on this guide https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/installation/.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't it for React Native Web? I have already built my app in only React Native, and I only want to build its web version (that shows up once we click on `Run on web browser` in the Expo cli window. Also, I couldn't find any steps to build in the given link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute this command:

```
expo build:web
```

it will generate in the web-build/ directory the static site to deploy in production.

Comment: I actually solved this problem using this same method, before I saw your answer. Here is the link https://docs.expo.io/distribution/publishing-websites/ (for others who might face this issue). Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Currently expo suggests to run `npx expo export:web`